# I installed android studio 3.1.2. and i noticed following errors

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

1. Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
2. Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality will not work properly

after reading answers on similar questions i tried changing gradle as suggested and it didnt work. Please help me out here

Specs- 32 bit and 3Gb RAM

Comment: Have you followed the Android programming tutorial?

Comment: Yes. I am following Udacity's program.

Comment: I don't know that one. My advice is to follow the default Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/

Comment: easiest way is go to youtube and search for a 2018 video that shows how to install latest android studio,follow the steps their,if you run into anything then ask a specific question

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Show your the Gradle build script.
I can assume you miss adding the Top-level build file.
Add build.gradle to the top level.

Like here:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.xx.y'
}
```

Comment: I have commented a screenshot of the error i am facing. As i dont know most of terms yet. Please look into it

Comment: Shardul, u should to learn Stack rules. Don't write similar things as question, ok? Write it in the comments, ok?

Comment: Try to update ur gradle plugin version. Here's detailed instructions how to do it step-by-step - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming when the design works and you get various options of phones its working. Thank you :)